# Struts tag "if test" in jsp

Tags: jsp, struts2

I am writing a condition in the jsp file based on which a image is displayed. Its something like this.

```
<s:if test='#session.member.memberisadmin == "Y" 
  && #session.member.hasPermission("Update access to white list terms")   =="true" '>

<a href="<gs:url action="listLabs" namespace="/labs"/>"><img src="<gs:url  
value="/images/labs/labs-48px.png"/>" alt="General Sentiment Labs"  style="margin-
bottom:5px;" /></a>

</s:if>
```

The problem is with the second condition session.member.haspermission, because when am using ||(or) instead of &&(and)  its working fine. Please suggest me a solution for this.

Comment: It works when you use || because the first condition is true. It fails when you use && because the second condition is false. So can you please explain what exactly is the problem?

Comment: What's the value <s:property ="#session.member.hasPermission("Update access to white list terms")"/>. IMHO identify whether user has permission or not in action and set a value there itself and compare in jsp.

Comment: when i separately assign the value of the second condition to a javascript variable, i am getting redcolor error on line in netbeans ide...  var result = "<s:param value="#session.member.hasPermission("Update access to white list terms")"/>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What type is result of `member.hasPermission()` method? 
If it return `boolean` then your mast check it like this

`<s:if test='#session.member.memberisadmin == "Y" && #session.member.hasPermission("Update access to white list terms")'>`

Comment: Re: (1), you can use `==` in OGNL expressions to compare strings. See the [OGNL language guide operators section](http://commons.apache.org/ognl/language-guide.html#Operators).

Comment: Yes, you are right. "If they are the same object or the equals() method says they are equal, they are equal." Don't know it, thanks.

Comment: the method  member.hasPermission() returns boolean   i.e., either true or false...

Comment: @Sangram Anand So, don't use this '== "true"' part. Your trying to compare boolean and String, don't do this ) Your already have a boolean - no comparison needed.